# Scala compile time check for location of constructor calls

Tags: scala

I have some code that has the invariant that an object must be constructed in the function where it is ultimately used (for various reasons related to global state that aren't ideal but are part of the assumption).

e.g. Suppose there is the function boo below that is responsible for manipulating moo.

```
def boo(mooGen: () => Moo) {
  val m = mooGen() // a new MOO must be created HERE
  m.moo()
}
```

Clients of boo that want to use boo must pass in a type of () => Moo, where the function generates the desired Moo.

Ideal client behavior:

```
boo( () => new Moo(// specific parameters here) )
```

The Moo is not created until inside the boo body.

However, a client can easily misstep with the following code:

```
val myMoo = new Moo(// specific parameters here)
boo( () => myMoo)
```

This breaks the invariant where we want the moo construction to occur only in boo.

So basically, I want to determine if the return value of mooGen is created within the call stack of the function or whether it was created beforehand.

There are many ways to verify this at runtime. However, is there any way to force this pattern at *compile* time? Using implicits or anything else clever?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put boo and Moo into their own object, together with a Token class, that can't be instantiated outside the object.

```
scala> object Foo {
     | class Moo(token:Token) {}
     | class Token private[Foo]()
     | def boo(mooGen: (Token) => Moo) {val m = mooGen(new Token)}
     | }
defined module Foo
```

Now what you want can be done:

```
scala> Foo.boo(new Foo.Moo(_))
```

And what you don't want can't be done:

```
scala> val mymoo = new Foo.Moo(new Foo.Token)
<console>:8: error: constructor Token in class Token cannot be accessed in objec
t $iw
       val mymoo = new Foo.Moo(new Foo.Token)
                           ^
```

But if the client *really* wants to he can - unfortunately - still get his Moo:

```
val ireallywantone = new Foo.Moo(null.asInstanceOf[Foo.Token])
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess if both the constructor of `Moo` and the method `boo` are under your control, and don't need to be written by clients, then you can make `Moo` take an implicit parameter, and arrange that the only place that a suitable implicit value is in scope is in `boo`.

It's not ideal... and you may not be able to make the type of the implicit parameter fully private (which would make it a lot more certain that the client doesn't instantiate a `Moo` outside of `boo`), because I suspect the compiler will complain about a private type leaking out in the definition of `Moo`. But even without that, it should at least help you prevent *accidental* creation of `Moo`s outside of `boo`; the client would have to deliberately get an implicit value to allow them to create a `Moo`.